# How to prevent page to scroll on top everytime when sweetAlert fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

I just want to ask how I can stop page to scroll on top everytime when alert is fire, I am using SweetAlert2.
I thought maybe my component is rerendering but thats not an issu.
Okay for information, i have tried backdrop: false and it is removing overflow-y and background css, also I have tried heightAuto: false and there is no change in it
I tried preventDefault() too, but that does not work too
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you use any this kind of code like window.scrollIntoView() ?

Comment: Have you tried this's answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135063/how-can-i-stop-sweetalert-scrolling-to-top-after-clicking-ok

Comment: @mayurkukadiya yes I tried and tested but nothing works as I already mentioned

Comment: And no I have'nt use any window.scrollIntoView

Comment: Can you create a working example (using codesnadbox or something)?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the community. Please can you provide your code in order to reproduce the issue?